# Evaluating Entity Framework properties only works on the second time

Tags: entity-framework

Using code-first, I have defined a relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ChildObject>()
    .HasRequired(child => child.ParentObject)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I can read other one-to-many properties from this class. Unfortunately, when I attempt to read a value from `child.ParentObject`, it throws this exception:

> A relationship multiplicity constraint violation occurred: An EntityReference can have no more than one related object, but the query returned more than one related object. This is a non-recoverable error.

I'm not entirely sure how that error could occur, because it seems to generate the correct schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChildObject]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ParentObject_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ParentObject]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
);
```

I discovered however that if I evaluated this expression in the debugger once, causing the debugger to catch the error, the razor page would render normally. So I realised to my horror that I could make it work by doing this:

```
@try
{
    @(this.Model.ParentRecord.Name)
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    @(this.Model.ParentRecord.Name)
}
```

Of course, this is absolutely ridiculous and I'll become the laughing stock of the next code review if I actually try to get it merged into the main development branch. This inconsistent behaviour seems very bug-like, and I'd like to learn how to work around it. I've tried searching for similar issues in Microsoft Connect, but I can't find anything like this. Surely I am not the first one to encounter this issue?

Comment: It would seem the generated query returns more than one `ParentObject` which means there's probably a reference from parent to child in the database (and your model) instead of one from child to parent.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I did think that was what had happened actually, but I don't think that's the case. I have added the partial schema above.

Comment: I take it that's a simplified schema? I don't see anything about primary key to make things unique...? (in case identity_insert is on)

Comment: It's simplified, yes - and perhaps the simplification hides the real problem because the issue seems to relate to another relation on the ParentObject - the query seems to include one join too many.